# How to control raspberry pi (gpio and peripherals) using an app from anywhere in the world

Tags: gpio, wifi, wireless, connection

For a school project I am undertaking, I need to send commands to a raspberry pi device wirelessly far away from the Raspberry Pi itself. The goal is to send commands which will:
i) Control a motor with the click of a button
ii)Start a video call using raspberry pi camera
iii)Stream microphone data
The raspberry pi itself will also be working for the user as device for themselves (through GUI software)

The catch is, this connection needs to be very secure. The user should be able to access and of the OS or the programming.

I have looked into Rest API but I have yet to use this and do not know of any limitations, and its security.

What are ways of doing this ? Specifically any good protocols of connecting the raspberry pi and the app itself, which is already quite secure, which I can implement increased cyber-security principles later on.

Comment: Have you tried Dataplicity? https://www.dataplicity.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **ssh** to connect to the RasPi and do your things. You can also use it as an ssh tunnel so you can use graphical user interfaces on the remote management computer to execute programs. Instead of an ssh tunnel you can also use a virtual private network using **wireguard** or **OpenVPN**. With the latter you are also able to have a bridged connection (with **tap** interfaces), so both subnets on the RasPi and on the management computer appear to be one subnet and you can manage things like they where running only on the RasPis network. That's the most comfortable setup but it is the most difficult one.

And all connections using **ssh**, or **wireguard**, or **OpenVPN** are strong encrypted and **very very secure**.

Answer (score 1):

Security is a complex subject, and I believe RPI.SE is not the right place to receive lecture on security. If this is the first time you touch security, you're overwhelmingly likely to hurt yourself by mistake. You may meet people with better knowledge on Security.SE and Crypto.SE, but they can't build a full solution on their own.

I recommend OWASP Cheatsheets for starters.

You should be aware that cross-posting is bad ethic on StackExchange sites, as I noticed you posted an almost identical question to Security.SE.

As you see, they're somewhat experienced with security, and can tell a lot of pieces of your goal are missing, and that's probably why you're overwhelmed by their comments.